# How can I enable flymake to collect information about problems in an Elisp buffer?

Tags: debugging, flymake

How can flymake be enabled on emacs-lisp code to collect information about problems in the buffer?

Have done `(flymake-mode)` to enable it. But getting the error Warning (flymake): Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function).

But if I do `M-x flymake-mode` I do get the highlight with the `!` sign.  But this does not happent when using calling `(flymake-mode)` in my init file.

Comment: Have you tried turning on `flymake-mode` in your Elisp buffer? If that doesn't do what you want, consider stating more clearly, more specifically, what it is you've tried and what you want to know.

Comment: I did `(flymake-mode)` to enable it.  But getting the error `Warning (flymake): Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)`.

Comment: Put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions should stand on their own. Only Q&A are searchable - only Q&A are useful to users looking for help with a similar problem.

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t` and try again: there should be a backtrace since it signals an error. Add the backtrace to your question. FWIW, I cannot reproduce it on GNU Emacs 29.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.30, cairo version 1.17.4) of 2022-02-02.

Comment: I did as you say, put `(setq debug-on-error t) (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)`.  Then loaded a file but flymake did not get activated.  No error logs are displayed.  I have to do `M-x flymake-mode` and start writing, to get the `Warning (flymake)`.  But cannot see any more error details with `debug-on-error`.

Comment: Check the contents of the `*Flymake log*` buffer (after restarting emacs to get rid of all the old crud if necessary). It might contain some hints. You might also want to add its contents to your question.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is run `M-x flymake-mode` in the buffer you want it enabled in.

If you want to enable it for all elisp buffers, add this to your init file:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)
```

To show the diagnostics, run `M-x flymake-show-buffer-diagnostics` in the buffer.

---

Regarding this error:

```
Warning (flymake): Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)
```

Flymake will automatically disable backends that cannot be run. In your case, the backend `flymake-proc-legacy-flymake` is being disabled, which is fine. If you run `flymake-running-backends`, you'll see that there are backends for elisp running.

---

You really should learn about the built-in help system. If you type `C-h f flymake-mode` you'll learn how to enable and use the mode.

Comment: `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)` did not work out as expected on an elisp buffer.  And still need to call `M-x flymake-mode` to activate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work out as expected on an elisp buffer"? What exactly did you do and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected that as soon as I write in the buffer I get the usual underlining with `!` at the beginning.  Which I get with `M-x flymake-mode`, but which I do not get when using elisp code `(flymake-mode 1)`.

Comment: You did not answer my question. How did you use the add-hook call? Did you put it in your init file as I suggested? If not, why? I never suggested calling `(flymake-mode `), so I'm not sure why you're mentioning that as if I did.

Comment: Did like this `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)`.  Then I loaded an elisp file and started writing.  But flymake did not start highlighting as I write.

Comment: Did you put that in your init file? Please be more specific.

Comment: Yes I did put it in my init file.  Then ran a new emacs session.

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful for you to be more specific and clear when communicating here. It's often been difficult to understand you.

Comment: Been trying a few things, but will keep your comments in mind.

Comment: Can you try putting `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)` in another file, say `/tmp/foo.el` and then starting emacs with `emacs -q -l /tmp/foo.el`? Does it work then? It should, so assuming that, try without the `-q` - does it still work? If not, then your init file is the culprit. If it does, then it should work if you put it in your init file. Also check the value of the hook: `C-h v emacs-lisp-mode-hook` - does it contain `flymake-mode`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on `M-x apropos-command  RET ^flymake RET`,  I would choose  `M-x flymake-show-buffer-diagnostics`

Also I would look at `M-x flymake-running-backends` and enable / disable the backends depending on how useful or annoying they are.

I wouldn't worry about `Warnings`, until I have to.

Comment: Can one put mentioned commands in init file as lisp code?

Comment: Consult the entry for `Command` in `(info "(emacs) Glossary")`?

Comment: Have done `(flymake-mode)`, `(flymake-show-diagnostics-buffer)`, ``(flymake-running-backends).  But I still have to do `M-x flymake-mode` to get the flymake highlighting.

Comment: The answer is most probably in the `ARG` param of  `flymake-mode` function.

Comment: Still same problem after using `(flymake-mode 1)`.

Comment: OP: Please don't use comments to ask and answer other questions that might be useful (e.g. to other users) on their own. Post them as questions instead. *Comments can be deleted at any time. And they're not searchable.*

Comment: You have complained I ask many questions.  Anyway, I still cannot get flymake to work in buffer if I introduce `(flymake-mode 1)` in my init file.